Jewish Holidays and Susceptibility to Tuma due to contact with liquids
What is a connection between Yamim Tovim an the 7 liquids that render food susseptible to tumah? Here's the background of the question. Elsewhere the connection was presented  (as written below) but not explained.
Mishna Makhshirin 6:4 lists 7 liquids which enable fruits and produce be susceptible to tuma upon a contact:
שִׁבְעָה מַשְׁקִין הֵן. הַטַּל וְהַמַּיִם, הַיַּיִן וְהַשֶּׁמֶן, וְהַדָּם, וְהֶחָלָב, וּדְבַשׁ דְּבוֹרִים. דְּבַשׁ צְרָעִים, טָהוֹר, וּמֻתָּר בַּאֲכִילָה:
There are seven liquids: dew, water, wine, oil, blood, milk and bees’ honey. Hornets’ honey does not cause susceptibility to uncleanness and may be eaten.
The curious fact is that each liquid is used during Jewish holidays:

On Rosh Hashanah we dip apple in bees' honey.
On Succot water is poured on the altar in the Temple and the world is judged for water.
On Shemini Atzert we pray for rain, which is water from shamayim, i.e. dew
On Chanukkah we burn oil on the menorah
On Purim we drink wine
On Pesach we talk about events in Egypt, such as the blood of korban Pesach and the blood of milla, red wine is used to symbolize the blood of korban Pesach.
On Shavuot we have a dairy meal which has milk products.

Is there a connection? What are the sources?
As pointed out, this connection (perhaps in a slightly different order) has been noted in several places, such as by R' Mordechai Kornfeld https://dafyomi.co.il/parsha/7liquids.htm, but not really explained. The food coming in contact with liquids not only becomes susceptible to tuma, but also it can acquire a loftier status of kedusha as maasrot, teruma, mincha. In what way is it similar to the way Jewish holidays impact Jewish people?

On shemini atzeret we start mentioning rain, not dew

@Joel K dew is defined as water from Shamaim and it includes rain

Brilliant observation. Never noticed anybody connect the dots. (And some of these dots are Rabbinic of later vintage or Minhagim, whereas this rule is from Sinai.)

It is also a question about a source, but I am asking what is the connection to holidays?

Perhaps this can be related to the idea that we are less careful in laws of Tuma during the holidays, so as not to alienate those who are less learned. כל ישראל חברים

I learned that Avrohom referred to YItzchok's "fire": what was dangerous for last sons who were sent east.  The sons that came from Ishmael were experts over water. Fire/Water don't mix: I am mesmerized at the consistent symbolism between the two elements (Jews=fire/sacrifice/learning Ishmael's line with Water/trading/gashmius) in Shamayim, the water supports the Fire which rests above - b'shalom.  Avrohom had 2 sons; he loved both;BORDERS. Is the union we stive for to bring in the final days Keys2Shalom? Separate/Accepting & Pure? https://etzion.org.il/en/holidays/shavuot/torah-fire-and-water
